# React Native, how to create multiple instances of the stateful component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Suppose i have a Component 'Drawing' which have its own states like brushes,color selection,background image,etc. 
I have another component by the name 'Multiple Drawings', now i would like to create multiple instances of 'Drawing' component inside 'Multiple Drawings'. When user make changes to any of the component then all the data should be constrained to that particular component(i dont want all the data to reside inside 'Multiple drawings' parent component ). How to achieve it

```
export default class Drawing extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state=
        {
            BrushWidth:10,
            BrushOpacity:50,
            SelectedColor:'red',
        }
    }
}
```

```
export default class MultipleDrawing extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state=
        {
            AllDrawings:[],
            SelectedDrawingIndex:0
        }
    }
}
componentWillMount()
{
    let allDrawings=[]
    allDrawings.push(<Drawing/>)
    allDrawings.push(<Drawing/>)
    this.state.AllDrawings=allDrawings
}
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            {this.state.AllDrawings[this.state.SelectedDrawingIndex]}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Quick Note: In componentWillMount(), you should update state with this.setState, not this.state.x=y.  Also, have you tried this and it did not work?

Comment: Jack, yeah i have tried with .setState as well, but not working. Does pushing component in an array will create a new instance or only save the reference?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you asking how to display multiple <Drawing/> components, or how to make each <Drawing/> component update itself? From what I can see in your example, you are only showing this.state.AllDrawings[0], so only the first <Drawing/> but you don't have anywhere in the code that you could update/change the state of each <Drawing/>. If you have more code, it would be helpful to share how you are catching interaction and how the interaction changes the components.

Comment: Doug, let me make my question short, as i have pushed <Drawing> component in an array(AllDrawings[0] and AllDrawings[1]) , does two behaves as a separate instances(copies) or single instance(changing one will change other) ?